# using i18n in Vue typescripte

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-i18n, nuxtjs

While learning TS on VUE there was such a problem

I have a component for rendering a menu, where I connect data

```
...
import ArrowRoundedDown9x6Svg from '~/svg/arrow-rounded-down-9x6.svg'
import headerNavigation from '~/data/headerNavigation'

@Component({
    components: { AppLink, Megamenu, Menu, ArrowRoundedDown9x6Svg }
})
export default class NavLinks extends Vue {
    items: INav = headerNavigation
    hoveredItem: INavLink | null = null
...
```

in it I connect data

```
import headerNavigation from '~/data/headerNavigation'
```

however, in this file I need to connect i18n to switch the language and I don’t know how to do it. there is no constructor in it

```
import { INav } from '~/interfaces/menus/nav'
import { TranslateResult } from 'vue-i18n'   // I create import 

const dataHeaderNavigation: INav = [
{
    title: "Home"
    url: '/',
}
export default dataHeaderNavigation
```

and accordingly I get an error if I try to do this

```
const dataHeaderNavigation: INav = [
{
    title: this.TranslateResult.get("header.links.Home").subscribe(value => { this.Home= value });
           ^^^
    url: '/',
}

Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

en.json

```
{
    "header": {
        "links": {
            "Home": "Home Page"
        }
    }
}
```

how to make a link to the translated element correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add a Vue instance

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { INav } from '~/interfaces/menus/nav'
const dataHeaderNavigation: (vue: Vue) => INav = vue => [
    {
        title: vue.$t('header.menu.home'),
        url: '/'
    }]
```

Also need to check that the interface allows you to return

```
import {LocaleMessage} from 'vue-i18n'
export interface ILink {
    title: string | LocaleMessage;
    url?: string;
}
```